# An inequality in Constantin's Navier-Stokes Equations book

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The inequality is listed in line 10 on page 29:
$$\parallel \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_{k}} \parallel_{L^{2}(G_{R^{"}})} \leq c \parallel\nabla \frac{\partial p}{\partial x_{k}} \parallel_{H^{-1}(G_{R})}.$$ First I would like to know how
$\nabla \partial p / \partial x_{k}$ is defined as a functional in $H^{1}_{0}$. Secondly
the proof of the inequality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the domain of the $L^2$ norm in the left hand side?